# Unable to play video file from URI Android 12

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-permissions, android-storage

I am trying to play a video in exoplayer from a file located in storage.

At first I get the uri for specific file and store it in a string variable.

```
private var myURI: String? = null        
private var getURI = registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts
                .GetContent()
        ) { uri ->
            if (uri == null) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    requireActivity(), "Please pick a video",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            } else {
                Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "URI is $uri")
                
            //Store URI
                myURI = uri.toString()
            }
        }
```

And further, I store the URI to the local SQLite database on the device.

I already have it's URI in local database so I don't want to use registerForActivityResult method again and don't want to choose video by Intent.
This is how uri looks in string format in database.

> "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A51407"

This is the code to access uri from the database

```
   val uri = URI("content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A51407")
   val videoUri = uri.toString()
```

I have tried to find a way to do so but can't find a way to implement this.

Comment: You said you had an uri -evrn it's uri- but you did not show how you obtained that uri nor how it looked like. Files mostly have no uri and certainly there is no such thing as it's uri.

Comment: Share your code. Thank you.

Comment: If one gets an uri from a provider one receives read and or write permission for that uri. You can give the uri to another app but not forward read and write permissions as they are for the original app only.

Comment: `I use registerForActivityResult method to get URI ` Unclear. Which one exactly? Not that it matters for your problem.. only sloppy info..

Comment: @blackapps As per my understanding, you mean to say that I cannot open the file just by URI, I need permission to use the file as done in app A when using registerForActivityResult method, but My question is also the same... How can I get the permission without using registerForActivityResult method.

Comment: You cant. Impossible. It makes no sense to transfer such an uri to another app. The security exception is telling you that.

Comment: Ok, I got you. But let's not use different apps, what if there is only app A .

Now assume I want to access the URI using registerForActivityResult method only once at first time and then I want to permanently use the URI for same file and not choose the file every time I want that file.

Comment: I asked you before to tell what you registered when using registerForActivityResult  as now that is no info at all as you can register for a hundred different things/activities/actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I store the URI to the local SQLite database on the device

That is not going to work as written. You need to switch from `ActivityResultContracts.GetContent` to `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`. You also need to call `takePersistableUriPermissions()` on a `ContentResolver` once you get the `Uri`. Otherwise, [your rights to that content lapse once your process terminates](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).